# Probability Word Problem

Tags: probability

Ten boys and girls write their names on slips of paper-one name per slip-to enter a prize drawing. Two of the names are drawn at random without replacement. If the probability that both winners are boys is $\frac1{15}$, how many boys are in the group?

I started off by noting that there are $10$ people in total, and tried multiplying it with $\frac1{15}$ and I got that there were $\frac{2}{5}$th but that's not possible, please help. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Let there be $b$ boys in the group of $10$ students. Total number of ways of choosing $2$ out of $10$ is $\binom{10}{2}$. Number of favorable cases i.e. the number of ways of choosing $2$ boys out of $b$ boys is $\binom{b}{2}$. Hence, the desired probability is $$\frac{\binom{b}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{b(b-1)}{10 \times 9}$$ Solve the quadratic assuming that $b$ is non-negative to get the number of boys.

Comment: im sorry im a little confused on the notation... for the b and 10 above the 2, is the b and 10 being divided by the 2? or what does that mean?

Comment: It's a binomial coefficient (Google it!), $b$-choose-$2$.

Comment: @uer8051: It is the binomial coefficient. $\binom{n}{r}$ denotes the number of ways of choosing $r$ objects from $n$ objects. $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r! (n-r)!}$